# Xamarin forms EntryCell loosing focus on entering a character in android tablet

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When entering a character in Entrycell under TableView, entrycell is loosing its focus and is only on Android Tablet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <TableView>
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection x:Name="TS">
                    <EntryCell PropertyChanged="EntryCell_PropertyChanged" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EntryCell_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == EntryCell.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    TS.Add(new TextCell() { Text = "Test" });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On resetting tablesection entrycell is loosing its focus

Comment: What is the desired behavior? You said 3 times that the entrycell is losing its focus but didn't mention what you actually expect

Comment: @HoRn I have a table section in that i have a enrtycell at 0. when typing something in entrycell the tablesection gets added with more cells.
Here the issue is when tablesection is getting added with more cells the entrycell at 0 is loosing its focus on each entering each character.

Comment: I hope this is clear.

Comment: @CharanDarbasthu You can try the solution in my answer. It works well.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT It is still the same with your solution

Comment: @CharanDarbasthu There is no problem with my test here. Are you a physical machine or an emulator?

Comment: Emulator - Android Tablet

Comment: @CharanDarbasthu Mine is also a virtual machine and it works fine... My API is 33.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ViewCell` to customize a cell:

```
<StackLayout>
    <TableView>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection x:Name="TS">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Entry PropertyChanged="Entry_PropertyChanged"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</StackLayout>
```

And then in page.xaml.cs:

```
private void Entry_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            TS.Add(new TextCell() { Text = "Test" });
        });
        Entry entry = (Entry)sender;
        entry.Focus();
    }
}
```

For more info you can refer to the official doc: [Custom cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview#custom-cells).